# Unable to parse function declaration with Python like syntax

Tags: python, pypeg

I am using [pyPEG](https://fdik.org/pyPEG/index.html) to parse the declaration of a function. Currently I have this written:

```
from pypeg2 import attr, \
                   optional, \
                   csl, \
                   name, \
                   List, \
                   Namespace


class Parameters(Namespace):
    grammar = optional(csl(name()))


class Function(List):
    grammar = "def", name(), \
              "(", attr("params", Parameters), "):"
```

So for example if I do:

```
>>> import pypeg2
>>> f = pypeg2.parse("def f(a, b):", Function)
```

I would expect `f.params` to contain `a` and `b` as parameters. Instead:

```
>>> f.params
Parameters([], name=Symbol('b'))
```

only `b` is found. Why is `b` the only found symbol?

Answer (score 0):

Because `name()` essential attach a matched `Symbol` to the `name` attr of the class. In your case the attachment of `b` overwrites `a`.

The official doc lists the following:

```
class Parameter(object):
    grammar = attr("typing", Type), name()

class Parameters(Namespace):
    grammar = csl(Parameter)
```

Here each `Parameter` has a `name`. The `Parameters` looks for the `name` attribute of the matched `Parameter` and put it into is internal `dict`.